# MVC 4 C# How to Retrieve Configuration Values in Controller to Bind Dropdown in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to fill a drop down in my index view with the values I have listed in web.config.

```
<add key="DropdownValues" value="Value1, Value2, Value3" />
```

I want to grab Value1, Value2, and Value3 from the config and bring it into a dropdown list with a friendly display name for each value.

Value from the list will be used when submit is hit and a server is queried and returns results into a table.

I am not sure how to code the controller part of this to grab the values and send over to the index page (using viewbag?) Other examples involved creating a ViewModel but I want to be able to add to the values in the future without having to re-compile the app that's why I want it in the config.

Please show me an example as I am still new to MVC.

I assume in the view I would do something like:
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YourModelProperty, 
   (IEnumerable)ViewBag.DropDownList, "---Select a value---")

Comment: Why not use a database instead of config file to store the values?

Comment: Because I would have to create a new database just to store a few values. All this app is going to do is take the value and run a query and show the results. Its a very simple app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 (In controller ActionResult Method): read the values from the config:

```
using System.Configuration;

string configvalue1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DropdownValues"];
```

Step 2 (In controller ActionResult Method): Parse them to an array by the comma and trim any space in front or behind the parsed text:

```
string[] values = configvalue1.Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Step 3 (In controller ActionResult Method): Declare a selectlistItem List, Iterate through array to populate:

```
        List<SelectListItem> dropDowns = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            dropDowns.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = values[i], Value = values[i] });
        }
```

Step 4 (In controller ActionResult Method): Assign them in your ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.DropdownVals = dropDowns;
```

Step 5: (In your view) set a dropdown list that is bound to your viewbag item. **You need to explicitly cast it to a IEnumerable SelectListItem object here or the razor engine will get angry!!!**

```
@Html.DropDownList("YourElementName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropdownVals, "--Choose Your Value--")
```

Full Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        string[] values = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DropdownValues"]).Split(',').Select(sValue => sValue.Trim()).ToArray();
        List<SelectListItem> dropDowns = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            dropDowns.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = values[i], Value = values[i] });
        }
        ViewBag.DropdownVals = dropDowns;
        return View();
    }
```

Full View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Html.DropDownList("YourElementName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropdownVals, "--Choose Your Value--")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
var GetWebConfigValue1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebConfigValue1"].ToString();

    ViewBag.WebConfigValue1 = GetWebConfigValue1;

    // Repeat the lines of code above to get more values

    return View();

}
```

**View:**

```
<select>
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose a Value</option>
    <option value="@ViewBag.WebConfigValue1">@ViewBag.WebConfigValue1</option>
    <option value="@ViewBag.WebConfigValue2">@ViewBag.WebConfigValue2</option>
    <option value="@ViewBag.WebConfigValue3">@ViewBag.WebConfigValue3</option>
</select>
```